# How to increase the size of the coefficient of a root

Tags: math-operators

I find that the coefficient 4 is very small compared to the symbol of the root. How does it increase in size?

```
$
\dt\psi&=\sqrt[4]{\dfrac{g^2}{R^2}\cdot \left( G_z^2-1\right)}
$
```

Comment: Did you consider changing `\sqrt[4]{...}` to `\sqrt[\scriptstyle4]{...}`?

Comment: Incidentally, how is `\dt` defined? And, why do you write `\left( G_z^2-1\right)` instead of `( G_z^2-1)`?

Comment: using \dfrac in inline math is forcing the body of the sqrt to b eover-large

Comment: your code fragment is showing `&` in inline math mode which is a syntax error, please post an example that actually produces the sizes you are asking about

Comment: in your real code is it  `\textstyle` sqrt (with no `&`) or an alignment (with an `&`) that is using `\displaystyle`  without knowing this it is not possible to know the relative size of the 4 and the sqrt sign.

Answer (score 1):

Your example fragment isn't usable so it is impossible to tell if you are asking about the display or text layout (which are quite different)

in inline and display I made some guesses as to error free versions of your original layout.

Using `\dfrac` in inline sqrt forces the root sign to be over-large which perhaps makes the index 4 seem too small.

I would use the default layouts as in inline2 and display2 but if you want a larger 4 you can use scriptsize rather than scriptscriptsize as in display3

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

inline
$
\psi=\sqrt[4]{\dfrac{g^2}{R^2}\cdot \left( G_z^2-1\right)}
$

display
\[
\psi=\sqrt[4]{\dfrac{g^2}{R^2}\cdot \left( G_z^2-1\right)}
\]


inline2
$
\psi=\sqrt[4]{\frac{g^2}{R^2}\cdot ( G_z^2-1)}
$

display2
\[
\psi=\sqrt[4]{\frac{g^2}{R^2}\cdot ( G_z^2-1)}
\]

display3
\[
\psi=\sqrt[\scriptstyle 4]{\frac{g^2}{R^2}\cdot ( G_z^2-1)}
\]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

One manual solution is available, that is:

```
$
\psi=\sqrt[\text{\normalsize4}]{\dfrac{g^2}{R^2}\cdot \left( G_z^2-1\right)}a
$
```

PS: I have removed `\dt` tag which produced error...

Comment: this takes the 4 from the text fonts not the math font, in the default computer modern setup that happens to be the same but in general this may not be the case.